# Error 405 al consumir Web Service

Tags: php, webservice, vpn

Este es mi código:

```
<?php    
    require_once("../nusoap-0.9.5/lib/nusoap.php");

    $wsdl = 'http://url';

    $client = 
    new nusoap_client

    ($wsdl, array( 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
        'trace' => true)); 

    $err = $client->getError();

    if ($err) 
    {   
        echo 'Error en Constructor' . $err ; 
    }

    $params = array();
    $params['requestIP'] = 'ip del vpn';
    $params['transactionDate'] = date('dmYHis');
    $hash = hash('sha256', implode('$$', $params));
    $params['transactionHash'] = $hash;
    $result = $client->call( 'getIdentificationTypes',$params);

    if ($client->fault) {
        echo 'Fallo la conexion';
    } 
    else {  // Chequea errores
        $err = $client->getError();
        if ($err) {     // Muestra el error
            echo 'Error EN ' . $err ;
        } else {        // Muestra el resultado
            echo 'El Resultado es';
            print_r ($result);
        }
    }
?>
```

Y me genera este error:

```
HTTP ERROR: Unsupported HTTP response status 405 Method Not Allowed (soapclient->response has contents of the response)
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo solucionar el problema?

Comment: ¿Esa es la URL: `'http://url`?

Comment: http://10.80.82.20:8080/MovilredPublicWS/MoneyTransferWS

Comment: Tienes que verificar con los que mantienen el Web Service. Esa URL parece no funcionar.

Comment: perdon  la url correcta es esta http://10.80.82.10:8090/MovilredPublicWS/MoneyTransferWS?wsdl

Comment: al parecer tenia mal la url pero ahora me genera el siguiente error Error EN HTTP Error: Couldn't open socket connection to server http://nanna:8090/MovilredPublicWS/MoneyTransferWS prior to connect(). This is often a problem looking up the host name.

Comment: Todo parece seguir siendo algún error respectivo al Web Servicie. ¿Te funciona poniendo la URL en un navegador? Si no funciona debes informarte sobre la forma correcta de escribir la URL.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda ya lo pude solucionar era                           
  //var $soap_defencoding = 'ISO-8859-1';
    var $soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';    en el nusoap